# Regex to get value within tag

Tags: objective-c, xml, regex, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a sample set of XML returned back:

```
<rsp stat="ok">
  <site>
    <id>1234</id>
    <name>testAddress</name>
    <hostname>anotherName</hostname>
    ...

  </site>
  <site>
    <id>56789</id>
    <name>ba</name>
    <hostname>alphatest</hostname>
    ...
  </site>
</rsp>
```

I want to extract everything within `<name></name>` but not the tags themselves, and to have that only for the first instance (or based on some other test select which item).

Is this possible with regex?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use an xml parsing library for your language? It's definitely possible with regex, but you may find using an XML library much easier and more efficient.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool for this kind of task is [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath).

```
NSURL *rspURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/rsp.xml" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
NSXMLDocument *document = [[[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:rspURL options:NSXMLNodeOptionsNone error:NULL] autorelease];

NSArray *nodes = [document nodesForXPath:@"/rsp/site[1]/name" error:NULL];
NSString *name = [nodes count] > 0 ? [[nodes objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] : nil;
```

If you want the name of the site which has id 56789, use this XPath: `/rsp/site[id='56789']/name` instead. I suggest you read [W3Schools XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp) for a quick overview of the XPath syntax.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>`<disclaimer>`I don't use Objective-C`</disclaimer>`</sub>

**You should be using an [XML parser](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=244288), [not regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542455/regex-to-indent-an-xml-file/542708#542708). [XML is not a regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357357/regexp-to-add-attribute-in-any-xml-tags/1357393#1357393), [hence not easely parseable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968919/when-not-to-use-regex-in-c-or-java-c-etc) by [a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege). [Don't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).**

> [Never use regular expressions or basic string parsing to process XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357814/when-is-it-best-to-use-regular-expressions-over-basic-string-spliting-substring/357847#357847). Every language in common usage right now has perfectly good XML support. XML is a deceptively complex standard and it's unlikely your code will be correct in the sense that it will properly parse all well-formed XML input, and even it if does, you're wasting your time because (as just mentioned) every language in common usage has XML support. It is unprofessional to use regular expressions to parse XML.

You could use [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/), with has [Objective C bindings](http://unix.freshmeat.net/projects/expatobjc/).

> [Apple's options are](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html):
>
> 1. The [CF xml parser](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFXML/index.html)
> 2. The [tree based Cocoa parser (10.4 only)](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFXML/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your language or environment, here are some perl expressions.  Hopefully it will give you the right idea for your application.

Your regular expression to capture the text content of a tag would look something like this:

```
m/>([^<]*)</
```

This will capture the content in each tag.  You will have to loop on the match to extract all content.  Note that this does not account for self-terminated tags.  You would need a regex engine with negative lookbehinds to accomplish that.  Without knowing your environment, it's hard to say if it would be supported.

You could also just strip all tags from your source using something like:

```
s/<[^>]*>//g
```

Also depending on your environment, if you can use an XML-parsing library, it will make your life much easier.  After all, by taking the regex approach, you lose everything that XML really offers you (structured data, context awareness, etc).

Comment: Yeah I am trying to use Objective-C. I didnt want to add any extra libraries or files, I thought maybe there would be a simple way for an  xml string i get returned

Answer (score 1):

As others say, you should really be using [`NSXMLParser`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this sort of thing.

HOWEVER, if you *only* need to extract the stuff in the name tags, then [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net) can do it quite easily:

```
NSString * xmlString = ...;
NSArray * captures = [xmlString arrayOfCaptureComponentsMatchedByRegex:@"<name>(.*?)</name>"];
for (NSArray * captureGroup in captures) {
  NSLog(@"Name: %@", [captureGroup objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Careful about namespaces:

```
<prefix:name xmlns:prefix="">testAddress</prefix:name>
```

is equivalent XML that will break regexp based code. For XML, use an XML parser. XPath is your friend for things like this. The XPath code below will return a sequence of strings with the info you want:

```
./rsp/site/name/text()
```

Cocoa has [NSXML support for XPath](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/QueryingXML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001258).